# Can I add hash (sha1) to value from input for compare two inputs?

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to compare two inputs.

First input is type "hidden" and get value from database.

For second input - value insert customer, but only if is same as in database, can her update his data.
Here is php:

```
<input id="pass1" type="hidden" value= "'.$row_pswd['pswd'].'" />
<input id="pass2" type="password" placeholder="password" required />
```

and script:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").<?php echo SHA1("value"."t&#sdhstöksdf54gh"); ?>;
var ok = true;
if (pass1 != pass2) {
    alert("Passwords Do not match");
    document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
    ok = false;
}
else {
    alert("Passwords Match!!!");
}
return ok;
}
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you realise you're voluntarily exposing users' password hashes? Not to mention the whole idea makes very little sense.

Comment: No.. This first password is too with hash. For another users without relevant.

Comment: Why do you expose secret values to the client side at all?

Comment: I need, that only member(customer) with her "id" can update own data. And  her password from database is only relevant for compare.
e.g. in status bar is `https://........./person_edit?id=8`. 
Now can every rewrite 8 to 10 and update member wih id=10

Comment: Why do not check the password server-side? Do you know JS is plaintext and everybody can do whatever they want in their browser?

Comment: @peter **hashes are not safe!!** They can be easily cracked within hours. They should be only there for securing the databse against breaches

Comment: Can u help me how can i add hash (SHA1) to input value? It was my first idea, but without success.

Comment: @Jonasw "hashes are not safe!! They can be easily cracked within hours" --- don't mislead people. "within hours" is too optimistic surely. Properly hashed secrets are not possible to recover for millions of years.

Comment: @zerkms without salts its an ease: https://crackstation.net

Comment: @Jonasw "ease" is a wrong word here as well. Since it still has too much "it depends" in it. Please stop confusing people even more. Otherwise, how about I provide you a sha1 hash without salt and you have a week to recover the original data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don`t think its a good idea to do that in Javascript. You kinda giving the way user password this way. Also hidden field with the password as value? Not good!

Move all this into php. Make the person first write the password, compare it in php and than update the info. If you want to do it in one page, use ajax.